# Can Bitcore decode a raw tx?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, raw-data, bitcore

I have a serialised transaction in raw hex format that I want decoded in JavaScript. Can Bitcore do that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcore makes it very easy to do this. Just use the Transaction constructor.

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore')

var txHexSerialized = "010000000...00000000";
var txDecoded = new bitcore.Transaction(txHexSerialized);
```